# read -t is not pausing my while loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, find

I'm trying to create a simple loop in bash that lists all the files in a directory, one by one.

I want to have to hit `Enter` before proceeding to the next one. I thought that adding `read` would make the loop pause. But it is not pausing. It is listing all the files at once. Here is the command I'm using

```
find . -type f | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; read -t 1; done`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @anubhava's answer, it doesn't matter where you use the other file descriptor. You can use it for reading input from the `find` process and take user input to prompt the next file on `stdin` (fd0). The key is you must have two different discriptors in use, one for the input of filenames from `find` and the other to take input from the user's keystrokes. For example, you could also do:

```sh
while read -u 4 -r line; do 
    echo "$line"
    read -n1 -t2 c
done 4< <(find . -type f)
```

It is functionally equivalent, aside from here, the result of the *process substitution* with `find` is redirected on fd4 while the user can provide input on `stdin` or after a 2 second timeout, the next file will automatically be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```sh
# redirect fd=3 from 0
exec 3<&0

while IFS= read -rd '' line; do
   echo "$line"
   # read from fd=3 and wait for 1 sec
   read -u 3 -t 1
done < <(find . -type f -print0)

# close fd=3
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: wow is that really the simplest way to do this? yikes

Comment: Sorry but what is `fd`?

Comment: `fd = file descriptor`

Comment: Reason why we are using a different file descriptor because other `read` with `while` is already reading data from `fd=0`. Other than `read -t 1`, there is no other reliable timer based `pause` command.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have to hit Enter before proceeding to the next one. I thought that adding read would make the loop pause

Try a [ProcSub](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and use a different [FD](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for the first **read**. Note that the inner `read` is just after the `do`.

```
while read -ru9 line; do read -p "$line"; done 9< <(find . -type f)
```

The `-u` flag from read means it will use the given file descriptor in this case the `9`

If your `bash` is new enough you can probably just use a `varname` for the [FD](http://%5B2%5D:%20https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Something like

```
while read -ru "$fd" line; do read -p "$line"; done {fd}< <(find . -type f)
```

Instead of hard coding a fix value for the [FD](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). Where `"$fd"` is just an arbitrary name/variable.

See also **help read** in your local terminal.

Comment: What does `-ru9` mean?

Comment: Hi, quoting `help read`  **-u fd     read from file descriptor FD instead of the standard input** and **-r        do not allow backslashes to escape any characters**. It can also be written as `read -r -u 9`.

Comment: I owe you an upvote. After digesting your ProcSub verbiage, you essentially beat me to the punch, so you get the nod.